# Grab Left & Right Volume Balance Levels

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, registry, windows-xp, regedit

I am trying to create a VB program in which it will constantly grab and display the current left and right channels volume level for windows 7.

Sadly i cant show code as i dont know where to start! Been searching the web and i seen information saying i needed to download or locate the file `"CoreAudio.dll"`. But sadly i searched my machine and cant find the file.

I just want to be able to have live feeds off the left and right channels and display it in a progress bar. <-- That i can get working but to do all that i need to acquire the information first! Which i cant do, could anybody assist me or point me in the right way for obtaining such information?

EDIT:
Perhaps i can read the values from the registry?
If someone could give me the location of the balance levels (registry location) that may help!

Would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Would anyone know the location in registry even to grab the values? Which can work in windows xp / 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just outputted the information to a .ini file as i could grab info from autohotkeys script i made and so i have a onchange event listener on vb so when the file changes (which will only happen when i output values) then pull the volume info stored.

Best and only way i could achieve this.

Would be best if someone could resolve the main issue and somehow get values from registry or some other way!